# Ionic tabs not proper responding in IOS

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

In ionic 3  Ion-Tabs are not properly working When personal hotspot is connected
in ios devices only icon click is working not title click

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about sharing some logs? I cannot figure your problem via what you wrote in the question.

Comment: Actually whenever this above hotspot notification came then bottom ion-tabs like 
Home, My order, messages, notifications and  profile is not working means unable to click on them, nothing affect on click any of them.